# Table not found error after submitting a spark script consisting with spark sql after enabling hivesupport

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I want to run a simple spark script which has some sparksql query basicaly Hiveql. the corresponding tables are saved in spark-warehouse folder.

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

```
from pyspark.sql import Row


spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/tmp").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sqlstring="SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID"

def queryBuilder(sqlval):
    df=spark.sql(sqlval)
    df.show()

result=queryBuilder(sqlstring)
print(result.collect())
print("Type of",type(result))
```

after performing spark submit  operation  i am facing bellow error

**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: lflow1; line 1 pos 211**

I could not figure out why it is happening. I have seen some posts from stackoverflow and they suggested that i have to enable my hive support which i have already done in my script by writing enablehivesupport(). but still i am getting this error. i am running pyspark 2.2 in windows 10. Kindly help me to figure it out

I have created and saved lflow1 and lesflow2 as permanent table in pyspark shell from dataframe. Here it is mycode

```
df = spark.read.json("C:/Users/codemen/Desktop/test for sparkreport engine/LeaseFlow1.json")

df2 = spark.read.json("C:/Users/codemen/Desktop/test for sparkreport engine/LeaseFlow2.json")

df.write.saveAsTable("lflow1")
df2.write.saveAsTable("lesflow2")
```

in Pyspark shell i have performed query

```
spark.sql("SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID").show()
```

and pyspark console is showing this

[image]

Comment: Could you show the part of code which creates table "lflow1"?

Comment: sure i have created  and saved lflow1 and lesflow2  as permanent table in pyspark shell .kindly look at my updated question

Comment: Ok
Can you see this tables by executing query manually?
(For example you can go to hive and type "show tables;" or do the same with sparksql

Comment: i have added the screenshots of pyspark manual queries

Comment: Why can't you use the same that you use in the shell: val result = spark.sql("SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID")?